# Request Date not display as date picker although I draw date picker when make search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I work on jQuery data table I face issue request date not display search related as date picker .

`tfoot` section is row that make search individually for any column .

search is working on  request date  as input text .

but only issue I can't solve it request date display as input text

desired result is to display request date as date picker with enable search

request date search working success as date picker but on header (wrong place) .

I need to display Request Date with Date picker on search row above header .

why I try as below

```
<table id="dtbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width:100%;padding-left:5px;
padding-right:7px;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
 
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Request No
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Employee No
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Request Date 
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                Reason    
                </th>
 
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
 
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestNo)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpID)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResignationSubmissionDate)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reason)
                    </td>
 
 
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Request No</th>
                <th>Employee No</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Request Date</th>
                <th>Reason</th>
 
            </tr>
 
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
 
 $(document).ready(function () {
 
       new DataTable('#dtbl', {
           "dom": 'rtip',
           "order": [[0, 'desc'], [2, 'asc']],
           initComplete: function () {
               $('#dtbl tfoot tr').insertBefore($('#dtbl thead tr'))
               this.api()
                   .columns()
                   .every(function () {
                       let column = this;
                       let title = column.footer().textContent;
 
 
                       let input = document.createElement('input');
                       input.placeholder = title;
 
                       $(input).css({
                           "width": "100%",
                           "padding": "0",
                           "margin": "0",
                           "height": $(column.header()).height() + "px",
                           "box-sizing": "border-box"
                       });
                       column.footer().innerHTML = ''; // Clear the footer cell
                       column.footer().replaceChildren(input);
 
                       var input22;
                       if (title === "Request Date") {
 
                           let datepickerInput = document.createElement('input');
                           datepickerInput.type = "text";
                           datepickerInput.id = "datepicker";
                           datepickerInput.placeholder = "Search " + title;
                           $(datepickerInput).datepicker({
                               dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                               onSelect: function (dateText) {
                                   column.search(dateText).draw();
                               }
                           });
 
                           column.header().appendChild(datepickerInput);
 
                       }
                       else {
                           $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                       }
 
                       $(column.footer()).html(input);
                       input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                           if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                               column.search(input.value).draw();
                           }
                       });
                   });
           }
       });
 });
```

expected result as image below

[image: image for search date picker]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line:

```js
let datepickerInput = document.createElement('input');
```

which will create another `<input>` element and add into the table header.

You should resume the previously created `<input>` element.

```js
let datepickerInput = input;
```

Also, from your code, there are a few codes that are redundant and unnecessary to add the `<input>` element into the table header. The simplified code is as below:

```js
initComplete: function () {
  $('#dtbl tfoot tr').insertBefore($('#dtbl thead tr'));
  this.api()
    .columns()
    .every(function () {
      let column = this;
      let title = column.footer().textContent;

      let input = document.createElement('input');
      input.placeholder = title;

      $(input).css({
        width: '100%',
        padding: '0',
        margin: '0',
        height: $(column.header()).height() + 'px',
        'box-sizing': 'border-box',
      });
      column.footer().innerHTML = ''; // Clear the footer cell
      column.footer().replaceChildren(input);

      var input22;
      if (title === 'Request Date') {
        let datepickerInput = input;
        datepickerInput.type = 'text';
        datepickerInput.id = 'datepicker';
        datepickerInput.placeholder = 'Search ' + title;
        $(datepickerInput).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          onSelect: function (dateText) {
            column.search(dateText).draw();
          },
        });
      } 

      input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        if (column.search() !== this.value) {
          column.search(input.value).draw();
        }
      });
    });
}
```

[JS Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ncmu3b?file=index.html)